# Case sensitivity of Xpath Function name() is inconsistent in Edge compared to other browsers

Tags: xpath, microsoft-edge

**Issue:**
When using `[name() = "SomeValue"]` in Edge, it will not return nodes if the `"SomeValue"` to match contains capital letters. Even if those capital letters match the node name exactly.

**Example:**
I have created **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/as5qxLgo/1/)** JSFiddle which exhibits problem. It uses two XML strings, both a subset of the books.xml sample on MSDN, where the first has capitalized node names and the second I have modified to use lowercase node names. [Fiddle with cleaner code.](https://jsfiddle.net/as5qxLgo/3/)

**Current Results:**
Running the fiddle in Edge, you will see when searching for `[name() = "catalog"]` where `"catalog"` is in any mixed case, the XPath will match nodes only when the search term is fully lowercase. Notice that it doesn't matter what the case of the matching node is, the term `"catalog"` will match a node if the node name is camel case, full caps, or all lowercase.

Edge will match all three of these nodes:

- `<Catalog/>`
- `<CATALOG/>`
- `<catalog/>`

When running the same in another browser (I have tested Firefox, Chrome, and Opera), the search term must match the node name case exactly, and is how I would expect XPath to operate. Out of the three node names above these browsers will only match `<Catalog/>` when using `[name() = "Catalog"]`

**Expected Results:**
I would expect Edge to behave the same as other browsers, since other functions like `text()` don't operate this way in Edge, which makes it even more inconsistent. This is shown in the JSFiddle as well.

Another reason I expect the same behavior, is that only XPath 1.0 is supported for all my tested browsers, so there should be no difference there.

**In summary:**
Is this a defect in Edge? / Is this allowed by the standard? If it is not allowed, I can write up a bug report to Microsoft. If it is allowed by the standard, do I just need to account for the browser difference?

**Additional Info**
Supporting existing software using jQuery, and looking for a solution which does not require additional third party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 is defined over a particular data model, which is not exactly the same as the HTML DOM. And the HTML5 DOM in particular was defined many years after XPath 1.0 was frozen. This means that anyone implementing XPath 1.0 over the HTML5 DOM has to decide how to map the HTML5 DOM to the XPath data model. It's very unfortunate if different vendors do this mapping in different ways, but it's not actually a violation of any standard. One of the key decisions to make in defining this mapping is how to cope with the fact that HTML5 is case-insensitive while XPath 1.0 is case-sensitive.

The underlying problem here is that you are using the HTML5 DOM to hold stuff that isn't HTML. This is a bad idea, because HTML5 tries hard to bend your content to the HTML5 model, which may corrupt your data in surprising ways. It would be much better to create an XML DOM for this data.

Also, using the predicate `[name()='SomeValue']` is bad practice anyway, because XPath 1.0 gives no guarantees about namespace prefixes in the result of the `name()` function. It's much better to use `self::SomeValue`, or `self::hh:SomeValue` if the data is in a namespace (although the mapping of HTML5 to a namespaced instance of the XPath data model raises another set of potential issues.)

Suggestion: use Saxon-JS as your XPath engine. That way (a) you get support for XPath 3.0 rather than 1.0, and (b) you're using the same XPath engine on every browser, so it will give compatible behaviour across browsers.

Comment: Follow-up question then: when you say "XML DOM" vs HTML5 DOM, is there such a container native to Edge or jQuery that you are aware of? Or are all documents used by Edge (even those created by jQuery since it uses the native parsing engine) going to be HTML5 based?
Unfortunately I can't add any third party software that we aren't already using. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: As far as I can see you have completely rewritten the example code, and there is no record in JSFiddle (as far as I can see) of what the previous code was. This means my answer is based on a completely different question which is no longer accessible. This is why StackOverflow strongly discourages questions which depend on links to external sites. I would love to pursue the investigation, but I can't do so if there's no accurate history of the conversation.

Comment: I have reverted the original link, and moved the updated link to the end of the paragraph if you still want to pursue. Sorry for the inconvenience.